# Mac drag and drop not smooth and fast as in Windows

Tags: windows, mac, drag-and-drop

I am new to MacBook Pro, just purchased. I was at windows doing drag and drop very fast as it is compared to mac.

Example: I want to drag a picture in the browser from my desktop in windows -> I will just drag the picture then I'll go to taskbar, I'll hold onto for less than a millisecond on the Chrome browser then I'll drop the picture in the chrome browser window.

Now what my problem in mac is it is very slow in doing this task I guess.

Example: When I click and drag the picture from the desktop and take it to the chrome browser already opened in the dock, I'll have to hold on to the chrome for more than 1 second then after I have to hold on to the window of chrome for 1 second, then the window of chrome blinks twice with blue outlining then after I can drop the picture in it.

This is my concern, that can I make this like it is in windows? Or just make the delay fast?

Please help. I do drag and drops very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the Chrome icon while dragging, to make it open a new window with the dragged file right away<sup>†</sup>.

Also, most keyboard shortcuts work while dragging.

Like you can drag to the Dock icon, then hit Spacebar to see all of that application's windows, hit Spacebar again while hovering a specific window to select that, and then stop dragging.

Or, while dragging, use Command+Tab to show the application switcher and then drop on the application's icon. Or click on, for example, the Chrome icon in the task switcher to make it open a new window with the file you're dragging.

Or, while dragging, use Command+Tab to activate the application in which you want to drop, optionally followed by Command+backtick to cycle between windows of that application, and then release the drag.

Or, hit F3 to activate Mission Control, to select the application of choice.

---

<sup>†</sup> In case it matters: I have enabled System Preferences, Accessibility, Mouse & Trackpad, Trackpad Options: Enable dragging. So, dragging does not require "truly" clicking the trackpad. Without that, tapping with an additional finger might count as clicking too.

Comment: In accessibility, there's also the simple "Spring-loading delay setting" - though I'm on a desktop with no trackpad so my other options in there are different to yours.